# Add link to help center in the canned First question comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, new-users, help-center

When reviewing a user's first question, we can opt to leave a comment, and there is the option of picking 2 canned comments:

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Or

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

None of them point to the relevant help center, where the OP can read more in detail what and how to ask in each community.

Can that link be added to both comments?

Something along the line of

> Hi and welcome to [community]
>
> Please [canned text]
>
> You can find more info on what is expected from questions in our [help center link]